# Game "energy" or "battery" backend?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So, I guess you already saw a game with energy, battery, life, ...

[image: Like this image (Top Right Corner)]

Like this image (Top Right Corner)

So, at start, you have 100% energy, every match or game costs some battery (let's say 20%). And every minute or every N minute, battery charge up for specific amount.

And the real challenge is, I have to store battery data in server.

And Client (Fron-End) should be always show the exact battery, and I guess using socket for this is not ideal!

Using Cron-Job is not a good idea to increase all user's battery value. What if I had millions of users? It's not optimal.

Please Help me on this.

P.S: I'm using: NodeJS & MongoDB

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that using socket not ideal. Since the backend stores the battery/energy value, whenever there is a change in the battery/energy value, using socket, you can send an update to all the subscribed clients and they easily update their view. Or, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to manage energy more convenient. Like asume 100% energy, then subtract used energy based on time of usage... something like this.